# How to create _init_.robot and use it for all robot files in the directory in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework, test-suite

I am trying to include_init_.robot file in the test suite. I have added a test implementation to check the method it would work, however I am unable to figure out it's execution. Code is as follows:

*init*.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Suite Setup      Initialization In Progress

*** Keywords ***
Initialization In Progress
    log many  THE CODE WORKS NOW
```

test#1.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case Execution
    log many  TC EXECUTED
```

Code used to run the test: pybot folder_name

Comment: How did you start Robot Framework and what is shown in the log file?

Comment: I am using Pycharm fot using robot framework. In log file, the details for keyword run from test#1.robot file is being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the first file is incorrect. You have

```
_init_.robot
```

while it should be

```
__init__.robot
```

When you do that the log will show this:

[image]